# how to create application that blocks incoming calls in the background - Android

Tags: android, receiver

I saw [Incoming Call Blocking in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120027/incoming-call-blocking-in-android) but for android 29 and higher i can't find a solution. Also i can't understand how to make receiver work when application is closed.
I have a three-part complex question:

1. how to make the receiver work even if the application stops?
2. how to get a phone number on an incoming call when api 29 or higher
3. how to make the window appear at the top when there is an incoming call
   please help me with this question.